# How to handle underscores in GDB break statement like b *"main.loop_b"?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

Trying to set a breakpoint for `b *"main.loop_b"`, I get the following error, although I've a process to debug:

```
You can't do that without a process to debug.
```

The problem is solved by changing `loop_b` to `loopb`, then `b *"main.loopb"` works just fine.

Any ideas on how to make GDB tolerate the underscore?

Comment: You don't need `*` to break at a label normally, right?  (`b main` or `b _start` is what I'd normally do).  You can always get the numeric address and `b *0x400010` or whatever, if `b "main.loop_b"` doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you use single quotes like `'` instead of double quotes like `"`